# Calendar Control with yearly view for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, calendar

I need to do an App with calendar, like Calendar app for iPhone 5 in iOS8, for example.

- I need to view complete year and after the view of month with selected dates.

do you know any control for get it?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FFCalendar control. It has Yearly, Monthly, Weekly and Daily Calendars for iOS.

Github Link : https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar

You can also search for more calendar controls on:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar

Comment: Thankyou @Dheeraj. this control is perfect, now i'm going to see how to adapte it for iPhone...

Comment: Hi @Dheeraj, how can i accept your answer??

Comment: follow this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow